# How to solve a facility location allocation (IP) problem in CVXPY

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, cvxpy

I am learning to solve optimization problems using CVXPY, so I started with the following simple facility location allocation problem.

[image]

The Code in CVXPY is given as:

```
Fi  =   np.array([1,1,1]) # Fixed cost of each facility
Ci  =   np.array([15, 10, 10]) # Capacity of each facility
Dj  =   np.array([5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4]) # Demand of each facility
Cij =   np.ones(m,n)


n   = len(Dj)
m   = len(Fi)


# Decision Variables
Xij = cvx.Bool(m,n)   # (m,n) vector
Yi = cvx.Bool(m)     # column vector of length (m,1)

# Objective
fixed_cost   = cvx.sum_entries(Fi*Yi)
var_cost     = cvx.sum_entries(Cij.T * Dj *Xij)
total_cost   = fixed_cost + var_cost
objective    = cvx.Minimize(total_cost)

# Maximum facility locations to be selected?
constraints.append(cvx.sum_entries(Yi)==2)

# Sum of demands allocated to a facility shall be <= facility capacity - 
# Capacity Fixed Cost
constraints.append(cvx.sum_entries(Dj * Xij.T, axis=0) <= Ci*Yi)

# Every demand point shall be supplied by only one facility.
constraints.append(cvx.sum_entries(Xij, axis=1) == 1) 


# Solve the problem
prob = cvx.Problem(objective, constraints)
prob.solve(solver=cvx.GLPK_MI)

# Print the values
#print("status:", prob.status)
print("optimal value", prob.value)
print("Selected Facility Locations", Yi.value)
print("Assigned Nodes", Xij.value, )
```

As per the last constraint, a demand location should be supplied by only one facility, however the output of **Xij.value** shows wrong results.

```
Using CVXPY version: 0.4.10
status: optimal
optimal value 91.0
Selected Facility Locations [[1.]
[0.]
[1.]]
Assigned Nodes to Facility 1) [[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
Assigned Nodes to Facility 2) [[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
Assigned Nodes to Facility 3) [[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

The Xij.value should be something like this:

```
Using CVXPY version: 0.4.10
status: optimal
optimal value 91.0
Selected Facility Locations [[1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]]
Assigned Nodes to Facility 1) [[1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]]
Assigned Nodes to Facility 2) [[0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]]
Assigned Nodes to Facility 3) [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Which means, facility 1 and 2 are selected.
The first three points are allocated to facility 1 and the next three to facility 2.

Comment: X == 1 is telling it that all values are 1

Comment: No, even when I remove the constraint, the X.value is still all one matrix.

Comment: Your code doesn't work, for instance m,n are defined after they are first used. If you can provide reproducible code compatiible with cvxpy 1.0 then I'm happy to help.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek & OP: Hi, I updated the code to cvxpy 1.0 and made it runnable